Can I use how much is it? when asking the the total cost of several different items?
Can I use how much is it? to ask for the total cost of my purchase when buying several different items (eg. a pen and a ruler)?
And can the seller answer like this?:
It's $5, please.

It's fine. But for the avoidance of doubt, you could ask "How much is it altogether?", or the seller could reply "That's a total of $5".

Yes. In fact, if you were to use the plural and ask, “How much are they?” it would suggest you assumed that each item had the same price.

Another typical reply would be, “That’ll be $5 please.”

How much shall I pay? It would be understood by the cashier that you are asking the total amount.

@JamesMathai Maybe a US/UK difference, but in the US I think we'd use "should I pay".

Probably not "it". It's a deictic, so How much is this?, he said pointing at the counter.

Thanks everyone! So, when asking the total cost for several different items (eg. a pen and a ruler) I could say: How much is this/ that? Or how much are these? Of course depending on how close I am to the items in question and even though this and that usually refer to a single item? But if I want to know the price of each, I'd say: How much are they? Or would this also imply the total cost?

I would always ask "What is the total cost please?" To which the reply could be just a figure "£5" or something like "The total will be £5"

Yes, you might say "How much is it" as long as you didn't mind "it" meaning some singular idea like the total price. Pronouns can have understood, unstated antecedents, so "it" might not mean just "the pen and ruler." For instance, it's common for a cashier to calculate the total and say "That will be $___," instead of "those." The understood singular antecedent of "that" is vague, but something like "the total" or "this purchase." (Sometimes singular antecedents can be even vaguer, standing for a general state of being, as with dummy subjects, or in "It's Wednesday" or "what time is it.")
So yes, asking "How much is it" when the total has been calculated makes sense and is idiomatic. But, when there isn't an idea connecting multiple things—like, if you stopped an employee in the store and held up a pen and a ruler—it would make more sense as "How much are these."

Yes, the cashier but what does the customer say? You get two upvotes and don't even answer the question? If the cashier says "that", the customer would have said "this" when referring to more than a single item. "What does this cost?" [pointing to items] Answer: That will be [$___].

@Lambie Hope that edit helps

Sorry but I simply think my answer is better in this case.

@Lambie Heh, I edited before reading yours. Gave yours an upvote and edited some more. I think we agree that using "this" while waving around an armful of products would be silly. It's all about understood antecedents!

Not waving them around but pointing at them all together in a cart, on the counter, etc. Thanks for the upvote. Some people here are serially downvoting me and it is beginning to seriously piss me off. :)

@Lambie I mean, the tooltip for up/down is "This answer is useful/not useful," right? Not "could be better/worse" or "I like/dislike it." I did downvote one the other day that I thought was just plain in the wrong (and left an explanatory comment as well, as ought to be good form when something is worth downvoting), and got called "unfriendly" for my efforts.

Anyone who thinks that "ruptured in twice" is OK needs to be downvoted. :)

When a purchase is made up of several items, "How much is this?" is fine.
Generally, the purchaser would point at those things or pointing would be implied. The items would be together on a sales' counter or at a cashier's check-out counter or in a shoppping basket. "it" does not work here, if you want to be really picky. It's not right in terms of deictics i.e., referencing things (plural, more than one item) in your speech.
More than one item:
How much are these?
How much is this? [referring to all of them]
How much is it? [Mistake buzzer: not for more than one item]

Oh my god: Please stop the downvoting. No one says IT for several items at once.

I didn't DV but doesn't "it" in "How much is it? stand for the total price? As in "How much is the total price?” Normally phrased as: How much in total? = How much money do I spend in total?

@Mari-LouA No, it does not. If you stand at a counter with items, plural, you wouldn't say "it". You'd say "How much is this?" If you have one item, you'd say: How much is it? It=the item.
